# removing xref tags in xml parse in python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am trying to parse in python using ElementTree some .nxml files structured like this.....

```
<body>
    <sec>
        <title>INTRODUCTION</title>
        <p>Experimentation with substances usually takes place during adolescence [<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="b1">1</xref>]. Adolescents are highly vulnerable to social influences [<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="b2">2</xref>], have lower tolerance levels and become dependent at lower doses than adults [<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="b3">3</xref>]. Adolescent-onset substance abuse is characterized by more rapid development of multiple drug dependencies and more severe psychopathology [<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="b4">4</xref>]. However, the majority of adolescents who experiment with substances do not become problem users. A better understanding is needed of the factors underlying initiation of substance use in adolescence versus heavy use and problem use. Specifically, if the liability to progress to heavier substance use is influenced by processes other than those that influence initiation, then primary prevention/intervention programmes can be only partly effective. It may be more successful, in terms of both cost and impact, to target those factors implicated in the progression to heavy/problem use. However, if the underlying liabilities to initiation and progression were strongly related, interventions could be tailored to both behaviours.</p>
```

Specifically I am trying to extract the text between the

```
<p> </p> tags.
```

However the elements

```
[<xref> </xref>]
```

in the text are interrupting the parse.

I have tried using

```
for sec in body:
    for p in sec:
        for e in p:
           e.remove (xref)
```

but the elements are not recognised. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean, "not recognised"?

Answer (score 1):

This would be more likely to work:

```
for xref in body.findall('xref'):
    body.remove(xref)
```

To be more in line with what you've been up to, try:

```
for sec in body.findall('sec'):
    for p in sec.findall('p'):
        for e in p.findall('xref'):
           p.remove(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I scrapped it all and used BeautifulSoup to just remove all the tags. Worked a treat. Cant believe I was such a schmuck.

Comment: Why not show us how you actually did it? Currently this is not much of an answer.